# function with .DATA how to convert to byte array

Tags: arduino

Sorry for the Noob Question.

I have a library  - RFM69 - https://github.com/LowPowerLab/RFM69

This provides the output as .DATA this appears to be a built in type?

Second I am trying send .DATA as a byte array but don't know what type it is in the first place. How can I find out.

Comment: I had a quick look at the .cpp code for the lib, I didn't see any .DATA. Can you be more specific about what you mean by "output as .DATA"?

Comment: @Greycon have you ever considered to read the header file as well? if you can't find something in a cpp its most likely in the .h

Comment: So true @piglet, so true. I must be getting old :-)

Answer (score 0):

Open the repository on GitHub. https://github.com/LowPowerLab/RFM69

Use the search field in the upper right ( with the in repository option) and search for ".DATA"

This will give you any file that contains it. Within seconds  you'll find out that DATA is a member of the class RFM69 which is defined in the file RFM69.h

You got the full source code. All you have to do is search, read and understand parts of it to get any answer you need.

https://github.com/LowPowerLab/RFM69/blob/master/RFM69.h

```
static volatile uint8_t DATA[RF69_MAX_DATA_LEN]; // recv/xmit buf, including header & crc bytes
```

I'll leave the rest to you.